# How to add a Cue banner/watermark to a text box in VBA?

Tags: vba, textbox

How to create a text box in vba, which shows a light gray text when its empty (like the "Search..." in the stackoverflow-search box)?

Comment: I found an approach here: https://www.codeproject.com/questions/1119403/how-do-i-add-a-cue-banner-to-a-userform-textbox-in but I have to figure out how to get the hwnd of my textbox

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can consider would be to have 2 text boxes - one with a background, one without.

The one without a background is on top, and is where you type your text.  The one *with* a background is behind it and cannot be selected.  When there is text in the top textbox, the bottom one is empty.  When the editable textbox is empty, the background one has text in it.

Or, if you're using an ActiveX Textbox as the top layer, you can use the `BackStyle` option to toggle transparency, like so:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus()
    If Len(TextBox1.Value) > 0 Then
        TextBox1.BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
    Else
        TextBox1.BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmmm...this seems me to be very unpractical to use this on a wide level. As you have to syncronize the two editboxes all the time. Namechanges, position & size changes always have to be done twice.

Comment: @Gener4tor Grouping the boxes will allow you to change the position & size of both at the same time.  The second option doesn't need double name-changes either - the background textbox shape is always there, but the ActiveX Text Box control toggles between hiding it or showing it.

Answer (score 1):

The best and easy thing I did was to create a test box with text as DD/MM/YYYY and the forecolor as &H8000000A& (Grey). This would bring that cue banner look in the textbox.
Second I entered 2 codes one of enter one for exit the textbox:

1. When you click the textbox the DD/MM/YYYY text would vanish and the original text user inputs would be of forecolor black

   ```
    Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
      TextBox1.Text = ""
      TextBox1.ForeColor = &H80000008 'User input in Black color
    End Sub
   ```
2. If the textbox is again blank, the textbox would show the cue banner in grey color:

   ```
    Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
    TextBox1.Text = "DD/MM/YYYY" 'Cue Banner Text
    TextBox1.ForeColor = &H8000000A 'GREY
    End If
    End Sub
   ```

Comment: The problem with this solution is, that the Value of the me.TextBox1 will change to "DD/MM/YYYY". This is a problem because I have to use any solution in a legacy system with hundreds of places where the value of me.TextBox1 is used directly.